# How to tell what an ingot, cube, or rare metal is/does

Tags: pokemon-duel

Upon opening loot boxes, you get assorted non-figure items.  I remember the tutorial going through how using these items in fusion boosts experience and what-not, but I can't find that information in the help menu.

What I'm more interested in figuring out is how to determine what I'm looking at when going through fusion.  Since tapping on them just adds or removes them from the fusion, I'm unsure how to get information on what each one is/does.  Here's an image to help illustrate the issue.

[image: Charmander fusion]

This image has my Charmander with 4 items being fused with it, but I've no idea what any of them are or what any of them do.  The one in the upper right has a green glow, as opposed to the rest being blue, as well as a "Cpt 1", which means nothing to me.  In the bottom left, there is one with some kinda flames or other effect, which also tells me nothing.

So, how can you see what a fusion material is and what effects it will have on the fusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Golden ingots are sold for money, Green metal is used for cl levels, and blue metals are used for xp leveling

Sell your gold ingots at the coin exchange in the shop

Comment: CLv and Cpt info can be found under Menu -> Help -> Other (App) -> Damage UP

Comment: The ingots each have different levels as well, which corresponds to the amount of XP, gold, or CL. However, some weaker CL ingots will not fuse with rarer figures.

Answer (score -2):

batophobia. the blue one is to use for upgrade exp the yellow one is use for sale the grreny one is use for chain level. Oops! I mean green.